# How to align horizontal line in layout exactly to image

Tags: android, layout, alignment, android-framelayout

So I have this [activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wTCf.png) What I want to do is to align the separator line and background image. What i do so far is just margin the whole layout with specific height but that is definitely not a solution since on new device they aren't aligned anymore. The whole problem is that the separator line is in layout. To avoid misunderstandings here is the line and image i want to align [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUd5.jpg). And here is the code

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/main_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mainborder"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    style="@style/HeaderText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/welcome" />

                <include layout="@layout/separator_line_smaller_margin" />

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                    <include layout="@layout/slider" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="203dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/profileInfo" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="bottom">

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                                android:onClick="goToProfile"
                                android:text="@string/myProfile"
                                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                                android:textColor="#4ED1AD"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/face" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mainborder"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/HeaderText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/comingViews"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <include layout="@layout/separator_line_smaller_margin" />

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/DoctorsLayouts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="49dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/face" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@mipmap/ic_data_range" />

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/Text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center|left"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="22.01.2018г. 9:00 часа"
                                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="65dp"
                                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="261dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Doctors"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                            android:text="Др. Хаус"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutPadding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/SecondHeaderText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/HowDoesItWork" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dummyText" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutPadding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="@string/Help"
                    android:textColor="#4ED1AD"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe split the background image in two elements? Like a workarround

Comment: `margin-top` 120 ?

Comment: @Jonathan how is this a solution? I don't really understand it.

Comment: @D.'s yeah but what happens when I play it on bigger screen

Comment: try `CoordinatorLayout` and tell me

Comment: CoordinatorLayout could be an option too, but what i mean with split background in two elements, is to create a LinearLayout for example, and put inside 2 images, one with the blue part and the other with de rest, so there you will have a reference where the divisor line is